# Atribuir o mesmo valor para o FormControl interno e externo usando ControlValueAccessor com ReactiveForms

Tags: angular

Eu tenho uma diretiva para colocar o valor tratado pelo DecimalPipe no valor do input sem trocar o valor do FormControl, ou melhor ainda, eu faço uma troca no FormControl sem atribuir isso ao input.

O resultado esperado é: DecimalPipe para o valor do input (como uma string) e float como numérico para o valor do FormControl, e isso tá ok, apenas não está aplicando a herança.

Eu uso um componente para prover funções para incrementar o valor conforme um parâmetro, e acesso esse componente através de um ControlValueAccessor. Entretanto, o valor impresso pelo FormControl "interno" e "externo" são diferentes.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enbqmf

Answer (score 0):

E se você tiver  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup; no seu componente de Input e passar o seu formGroup pra dentro dele? Acho que resolve seu problema

antes :

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="localForm">
```

depois:

```
  <app-input-number step="0.01" name="decimal" [formGroup]="testForm"></app-input-number>
```

no input e remover o fromGroup:

```
  <ng-container [formGroup]="formGroup">
    formControlName="{{ name }}"
```